# designing a drill jig for manufacturing a finished product

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design, tools, drilling, product-design

what will be suitable drill jig for the given product? since the drill is not straight. so i'm not sure for the suitable design, kindly looking for kind help. thanks in advance!

if it would have conventional product for drilling three holes, i would have chossen **template jig** and **drill bushes of suitable dimension**. [image]

Comment: While you could make a jig, wear and tear would be excessive if you did not also fix the root of the problem.  Standard drill bit points are designed to run exceptionally well in straight holes with a center punched locations.  I suggest you use a different cutter in addition to jigging.  Endmills, ball burrs, and the like come in many sizes and handle odd surfaces rather well.  If you want less wear on the endmill or can't get one of the exact size for cheap enough, you could 2-step it by surfacing the location first with the endmill and then doing for the drill bit.

Comment: If it has to be close tolerance in medium quantities, milling it might actually be a reasonable way to go

Comment: did you manufacture the item?

Comment: Make the top flat, drill the holes, then face it on a lathe.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your tolerances, it may be a reasonable case for some cheap additive plastic jigs.  You get the benefits of being able to make fancy shapes at the expense of shooting yourself in the foot with your own design.

For long life of a jig try to avoid cutter contact with the plastic.  Metal inserts help with heat also!  If the shank is a larger diameter than the cutter, having the jig only youch the shank will extend the life of the jig.  You can also add bearings, collars, or even bushings to bits to achieve the same or better effect.

Account for chip egress.  If the chips are hard and hot enough, they can damage a plastic jig.

On that surface, a standard 2-flute drill point is going to want to walk. That equates to cutter forced against jig, cutting into it over time.  You can solve that by using a different cutter, but may choose not to after weighing all costs.